# Using SDL-C library, mouse motion bug in simple game

Tags: c, events, event-handling, sdl

I am trying to make a simple game. I have the following code with which I am placing some images on the screen. I want to make it so that when left click is pressed and I move the mouse, those images are continuously put on the screen (so that the player does not have to click many times over.) I have the following:

```
SDL_Surface *mur = NULL, *caisse = NULL, *objectif = NULL, *mario = NULL;
     SDL_Rect position;
     SDL_Event event;

     int continuer = 1, clic_gauche = 0, clic_droit = 0;
     int objet_actuel = MUR, i = 0, j = 0;
     int carte[NB_BLOCS_LARGEUR][NB_BLOCS_HAUTEUR] = {0};

     //Chargement des objets et du niveau.
     mur = IMG_Load("mur.jpg");
     caisse = IMG_Load("caisse.jpg");
     objectif = IMG_Load("objectif.png");
     mario = IMG_Load("mario_bas.gif");

     if(!Charger_Niveau(carte)) //Erreur de chargement du niveau.
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

     while(continuer)
     {
         SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
         switch(event.type)
         {

             case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                  if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                  {
                      carte[event.button.x/TAILLE_BLOC][event.button.y/TAILLE_BLOC] = objet_actuel; //On met l'objet actuellement choisi a l'endroit du clic.
                      clic_gauche = 1; //On retient le fait que le dernier clic etait un clic gauche.
                  }
                  else if (event.button.button = SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)
                  {
                      carte[event.button.x/TAILLE_BLOC][event.button.y/TAILLE_BLOC] = VIDE; //On vide le bloc ou s'est produit le clic droit.
                      clic_droit = 1; //On retient le fait que le dernier clic etait un clic droit.
                  }
                  break;

             case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP: //On desactive le booleen qui disait qu'un bouton etait enfonce.
                  if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                      clic_gauche = 0;
                  else if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)
                      clic_droit = 0;
                  break;

              case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                   if(clic_gauche == 1)
                   {
                       carte[event.motion.x / TAILLE_BLOC][event.motion.y / TAILLE_BLOC] == objet_actuel;
                   }
                   else if(clic_droit == 1)
                   {
                       carte[event.motion.x/TAILLE_BLOC][event.motion.y/TAILLE_BLOC] == VIDE;
                   }
                   break;
```

The loop then continues checking if some keys have been pressed, then I blit all the images that were loaded using the double matrix carte and I refresh the screen. The problem is mouse motion doesn't work. Debugging events is rather difficult...does anyone see an evident problem with the code?

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether the case `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` is being reached, and is failing to do what you want, or whether the problem is that an event of type `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` is not being delivered.  Can you add some print statements in the `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` case to show the values of `event.motion.x` and `event.motion.y` that are arriving...maybe outside the `if`/`else` block for this case?

Comment: SDL_MOUSEMOTION is reached normally when I move the mouse, but it never enters the if statement, no matter whether left or right click is pressed. It doesn't enter the if statement even when I set clic_gauche to 1 from the beginning. The coordinates are also correct, I checked.

Comment: Unrelated, but `else if (event.button.button = SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)` is assignment (`=`), not equality checking (`==`), so that's probably not what you meant.

Comment: Ah! the opposite problem affects your SDL_MOUSEMOTION handler: you're not _assigning_ `object_actif` or `VIDE` into the map/`carte`...you're _comparing_.  Change those to use `=` not `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not *assigning* into `carte` in the `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` handler, you're *comparing*.

(Unfortunately, any expression is allowed to be a statement in C, even if it has no effects/side-effects on the program, so the compiler doesn't necessarily help you find these issues.)

Your handler should be:

```
  case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
       if(clic_gauche == 1)
       {
           carte[event.motion.x / TAILLE_BLOC][event.motion.y / TAILLE_BLOC] = objet_actuel;
       }
       else if(clic_droit == 1)
       {
           carte[event.motion.x/TAILLE_BLOC][event.motion.y/TAILLE_BLOC] = VIDE;
       }
       break;
```

(Note the single `=` in each case of the if/else)

Also, the inverse issue affects the handler for `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` where you're assigning to `event.button.button` rather than comparing its value against the constant `SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT`.

Note: for this reason, many developers have taken to putting the constant on left-hand side of a comparison, so that the compiler *will* give you an error if you mistype the operator.  E.g.,

```
else if (SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT == event.button.button)
```

Comment: There are many things that valid C but very likely to be mistakes - that's why compiler have distinction between "error" and "warning". Clang and gcc are particularly good at that - I think in 95% cases warning actually points at a programmer's mistake. Even infamous microsoft's compiler now issues a warnings for comparison with no effect or assignment in condition (although they made latter case difficult to suppress, so no kudos here). gcc and others did that for about 20 years. One just have to ask compiler for a little help with some warning flags.

Comment: Heh. I just assumed the program compiled cleanly.  The team I work with does `-pedantic -Wall -Werror` as a matter of daily practice in all build scripts...I forgot the world doesn't typically work that way.  You make an excellent point, and I have changed the wording to reflect it; I wish more universities would encourage use of such compiler support.

Comment: Yeah, `-Wall` is enough in that case, but I use much more than that (like `-Winit-self` - sadly not even in `-Wextra`). And I just verifyed that `/W2` for MSVC cl issues warning too. To make matters worse some SDL tutorials recommends `-w` flag without even explaining what it does (suppresses all warnings).

Comment: I am using -Wall, but I totally missed this. I was convinced the error was something more complicated and my eyes just skipped those comparisons so many times. Thank you!